# nav stack missing from UbuntuARM install

Tags: ros, navigation, beaglebone, armhf, odroid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this page:
http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM
and have it working, but cannot find the install package for navigation.
apt-cache search ros-groovy
does not show up a nav package other than nav_msgs.
So, of course,
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-navigation
just returns this:
Unable to locate package ros-groovy-navigation

How do I get programs like amcl, move_base, etc. installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94791/nav-stack-missing-from-ubuntuarm-install/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the build farm status and the navigation packages are all in red (missing) for groovy.
http://namniart.com/repos/status/groovy.html

However, good news, they are all green for hydro.
http://namniart.com/repos/status/hydro.html

So I am moving to Ubuntu 13.04 and hydro.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2013-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1